# Float to minutes and seconds within time range in R?

Tags: r, datetime

I have time-series data collected by the minute in the hh:mm:ss range (08:30:00, 15:00:00). The variable I'm dealing with is a sort-of float factor, with values like this:

```
time.float
48.13333
56.66667
65.93333
113.33333
94.60000
```

I want to take the values in `time.float` and convert them in to hh:mm:ss format in the above time range.

I'm lost as to how to approach this. Is there a built-in function to assign a time value in a certain range in R?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `as.difftime` to create a minutes object that can be added to the start point. Like:

```
out <- as.difftime(dat$time.float, units="mins") + as.POSIXct("08:30:00", format="%H:%M:%S")
```

Which you can output in whatever format you want as a text string:

```
format(out, "%H:%M:%S")
#[1] "09:18:07" "09:26:40" "09:35:55" "10:23:19" "10:04:36"
```

Where `dat` was:

```
dat <- structure(list(time.float = c(48.13333, 56.66667, 65.93333, 113.33333, 
94.6)), .Names = "time.float", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: Very nice solution...I missed that part about specific time range and reference point.